# Is there any risk in using MacBook Pro with the lid closed (External Monitor)?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, macbook, external-display, cooling

I have an older MacBook Pro ( 2007, 2.33GHz ) running 10.6.6 that I'm hoping to use as a media only ( movies & music ) computer. I'd like to connect it to an external monitor and leave the lid closed.

Would doing so pose any risk to the laptop? I heard that the a good amount of heat is dispersed through the keyboard and that leaving the lid closed could cause the computer to overheat. Is there any truth to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From personal experience, I use my MacBook Pro 3.1 in a [HengeDock](http://hengedocks.com/) with the lid closed 24/7. I often use it to do processor-intensive tasks (rendering video, etc) and I've never had a problem. Most of the heat comes out the back by the fans (just like it's designed to do). There's no risk to the computer.

Answer (score 2):

No risk.  The thermals of the MBP are well designed enough the lid concern to be moot.

This could be said about most laptops.

Answer (score 1):

The latest MacBook Pros have the vents on the top near the keyboard. If you kept the screen closed halfway overnight for long renders, the screen gets brown burn/smoke marks from the heat!

I just had this happen to me today. NOT GOOD!

Answer (score 1):

I usually stick my Retina 15" under my iMac Screen and work off this instead however Ive noticed that Ive got really bad ghosting on my screen now (burnt in images) which is 1. really annoying and 2. very disappointing

Apparently this is down to poor screens produced by LG (No surprises there)... the latest models have screens by Samsung which are supposed to be far better.

The point here is.... yes they get toasty .... the heating seems to have burnt images into my screen.

So id say have it open if your working on it and just mirror the displays.